# Python Pandas New column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas data frame ***df.drop*** which has two date columns *Joined Date* and *Terminated Date*.
i want to get the difference(in days) between terminated date and joined date. but there is a text value in terminated date *'Not terminated'*.
hence i tried to convert it in to today's date and then get the difference. below is the code which i tried for convertion

```
import time
today=time.strftime(("%Y-%m-%d"))
df_drop['TerminatedDate_new'] = [today if x=='Not_Terminated' else df_drop['TerminatedDate'] for x in df_drop['TerminatedDate']]
```

although it gives correct answer(today) for 'Not_Terminated' rows, for date values, it gives entire df_drop['TerminatedDate'] column instead of the existing date(else part of the code).
how do i change it so that it select the same raw and give the existing date value?

also is there easy method to get the difference without separably calculating df_drop['TerminatedDate_new']

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a bit long. A better way to do it is

```
df['TerminatedDate'].replace({'Not_Terminated':today}, inplace=True)
```

If you don't want replace the old column, you could save it to new column.

```
df['new_col'] = df['TerminatedDate'].replace({'Not_Terminated':today})
```

The problem with your code is this part `else df_drop['TerminatedDate'] for x` as it replaces the a cell by the entire column. It should be  `else x for x`.

If you want to get the difference in one single action, you would have to create a custom function and apply it row wise.

```
def get_dif(start,end):
    if end == "Not_Terminated":
        end = today
    return end-start
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda df: get_dif(df['JoinedDate'],df['TerminatedDate'], axis=1)
```

Comment: complete answer with great explanation. thanks very much